# How to import string extracted from a file in python?

Tags: python, regex, file, odoo, file-handling

I have one issue over here in file importing data from text file using python.

I have data like this in my file.

```
{1:F05ABCDRPRAXXX0000000000}{2:I1230AGRIXXPRXXXXN}{4:
:20:1234567980
:25:AB123465789013246578900000000000
:28c:110/1123156
-}
```

So from above data I want to fetch data after `{4:` and line by line like first line is `:20:1234567980` and so on.

I want to split data using regular expression So if any python expert have idea how make regular expression for this so provide in answer it will help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the lines in a file use

```
lines = list()
with open("yourfiile.txt") as f:
  for line in f:
    lines.append(line)
lines.pop(0) #remove the first line (which ends with "{4:")
#do what you want with list of lines
```